# how to create a category class in Cocoa objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm creating an iPhone app that needs to add a custom category to extend uinavigationbar. Can anyone give me a code example of how I would create and implement this category to extend this class?

Comment: I am curious as to how you decided you need a category, when you do not know how to implement a category? Are you sure this is what you meant?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Customizing Existing Classes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW1) chapter of the Objective-C Programming Guide is the definitive reference.

Comment: This link is broken and I can't seem to find the new link. However there is now a chapter titled "Customizing existing classes" that provides a little bit of info on Categories:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: And a related question that clarified (for me) why Categories and Extensions are documented together (and have similar syntax), but are different things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685679/minutia-on-objective-c-categories-and-extensions

Answer (score 3):

[Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Categories) what Wikipedia has in the way of categories (with samples) in Objective-C. It is a pretty useful tutorial on the subject.