# Minutia on Objective-C Categories and Extensions

Tags: objective-c

I learned something new while trying to figure out why my readwrite property declared in a private Category wasn't generating a setter.  It was because my Category was named:

```
// .m
@interface MyClass (private)
@property (readwrite, copy) NSArray* myProperty;
@end
```

Changing it to:

```
// .m
@interface MyClass ()
@property (readwrite, copy) NSArray* myProperty;
@end
```

and my setter is synthesized. I now know that Class Extension is not just another name for an anonymous Category.  Leaving a Category unnamed causes it to morph into a different beast: one that now gives compile-time method implementation enforcement and allows you to add ivars.  I now understand the general philosophies underlying each of these: Categories are generally used to add methods to any class at runtime, and Class Extensions are generally used to enforce private API implementation and add ivars.  I accept this.

But there are trifles that confuse me.  First, at a hight level: Why differentiate like this?  These concepts seem like similar ideas that can't decide if they are the same, or different concepts.  If they are the same, I would expect the exact same things to be possible using a Category with no name as is with a named Category (which they are not).  If they are different, (which they are) I would expect a greater syntactical disparity between the two.  It seems odd to say, "Oh, by the way, to implement a Class Extension, just write a Category, but leave out the name. It magically changes."

Second, on the topic of compile time enforcement: If you can't add properties in a named Category, why does doing so convince the compiler that you did just that?  To clarify, I'll illustrate with my example.  I can declare a readonly property in the header file:

```
// .h
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (readonly, copy) NSString* myString;
@end
```

Now, I want to head over to the implementation file and give myself private readwrite access to the property. If I do it correctly:

```
// .m
@interface MyClass ()
@property (readwrite, copy) NSString* myString;
@end
```

I get a warning when I don't synthesize, and when I do, I can set the property and everything is peachy. But, frustratingly, if I happen to be slightly misguided about the difference between Category and Class Extension and I try:

```
// .m
@interface MyClass (private)
@property (readwrite, copy) NSString* myString;
@end
```

The compiler is completely pacified into thinking that the property is readwrite.  I get no warning, and not even the nice compile error "Object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found" upon setting myString that I would had I not declared the readwrite property in the Category.  I just get the "Does not respond to selector" exception at runtime. If adding ivars and properties is not supported by (named) Categories, is it too much to ask that the compiler play by the same rules?  Am I missing some grand design philosophy?

Comment: I believe you meant `readwrite` for the private myString property declarations. I edited to reflect that; hopefully that's correct.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Class extensions were added in Objective-C 2.0 to solve two specific problems:

1. Allow an object to have a "private" interface that is checked by the compiler.
2. Allow publicly-readable, privately-writable properties.

## Private Interface

Before Objective-C 2.0, if a developer wanted to have a set of methods in Objective-C, they often declared a "Private" category in the class's implementation file:

```
@interface MyClass (Private)
- (id)awesomePrivateMethod;
@end
```

However, these private methods were often mixed into the class's `@implementation` block (*not* a separate `@implementation` block for the `Private` category). And why not? These aren't really extensions to the class; they just make up for the lack of public/private restrictions in Objective-C categories.

The problem is that Objective-C compilers assume that methods declared in a category will be implemented elsewhere, so they don't check to make sure the methods are implemented. Thus, a developer could *declare* `awesomePrivateMethod` but fail to implement it, and the compiler wouldn't warn them of the problem. That is the problem you noticed: in a category, you can declare a property (or a method) but fail to get a warning if you never actually implement it -- that's because the compiler expects it to be implemented "somewhere" (most likely, in another compilation unit independent of this one).

Enter class extensions. Methods declared in a class extension are assumed to be implemented in the main `@implementation` block; if they're not, the compiler will issue a warning.

## Publicly-Readable, Privately-Writeable Properties

It is often beneficial to implement an immutable data structure -- that is, one in which outside code can't use a setter to modify the object's state. However, it can still be nice to have a writable property for *internal* use. Class extensions allow that: in the public interface, a developer can declare a property to be read-only, but then declare it to be writable in the class extension. To outside code, the property will be read-only, but a setter can be used internally.

## So Why Can't I Declare a Writable Property in a Category?

Categories cannot add instance variables. A setter often requires some sort of backing storage. It was decided that allowing a category to declare a property that likely required a backing store was A Bad Thing™. Hence, a category cannot declare a writable property.

## They Look Similar, But Are Different

The confusion lies in the idea that a class extension is just an "unnamed category". The syntax is similar and implies this idea; I imagine it was just chosen because it was familiar to Objective-C programmers and, in some ways, class extensions are like categories. They *are* alike in that both features allow you to add methods (and properties) to an existing class, but they serve different purposes and thus allow different behaviors.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I was familiar with the pre 2.0 private Category method of declaring private methods which were implemented in the class's @implementation. I also apparently missed the memo on the advent of the Extension.  To me, it appeared that many devs were simply opting for the less explicit method of not naming their private Categories, which I didn't like.  The moral I needed to find was basically that there is no such thing as an unnamed Category. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You're confused by the syntactic similarity. A class extension is *not* just an unnamed category. A class extension is a way to make part of your interface private and part public — both are treated as part of the class's interface declaration. Being part of the class's interface, an extension must be defined as part of the class.

A category, on the other hand, is a way of adding methods to an existing class at runtime. This could be, for example, in a separate bundle that is only loaded on Thursdays.

For most of Objective-C's history, it was impossible to add instance variables to a class at runtime, when categories are loaded. This has been worked around very recently in the new runtime, but the language still shows the scars of its fragile base classes. One of these is that the language doesn't support categories adding instance variables. You'll have to write out the getters and setters yourself, old-school style.

Instance variables in categories are somewhat tricky, too. Since they aren't necessarily present when the instance is created and the initializer may not know anything about them, initializing them is a problem that doesn't exist with normal instance variables.

Comment: Yes, I'm confused by the syntactic similarity =). I can see that Extensions are a fundamentally different concept than Categories. I was wondering why such a small difference in sytax leads to such different behaviors.  To those unfamiliar with Extenstions (me, circa yesterday), an Extension IS syntactically an unnamed Category.

Comment: @Matt Wilding: We'll have to hope one of Apple's Cocoa team stops by for an official answer to "why". Secret categories were the old way of adding "private" behavior to a class, so my assumption is that it just seemed convenient to use a similar syntax for the superior replacement. I doubt they realized how confusing it would appear to people who hadn't been using Cocoa all along.

Comment: We couldn't come up with anything better and extensions really are kinda like categories with slightly different semantics.  Seemed natural enough at the time.

Comment: @bbum: Thanks for official insight.  I'm curious, before class Extensions were added to Objective-C, what did declaring a Category with no name do?  Was it a compile error, or did class Extensions replace the ability to do so?

Comment: I don't specifically remember, but I'm almost certain it was a compilation error (which was why we could use it for extensions -- you'd be amazed by the number of "brilliant" syntactic inventions that are actually impossible because of some wonky validity in C++).

Comment: @Matt Wilding: It just wouldn't parse. The parser expected parentheses with one or more valid characters inside, so you'd get "error: parse error before ')' token"

Comment: Okay, that makes perfect sense now. I'm glad to know there is and never was such thing as a Category with no name.  That alleviates the syntactical confusion for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a property in a category, you just can't synthesize it. If you use a category, you will not get a compile warning because it expects the setter to be implemented in the category.

Comment: Of course. I should have thought of that. I spend so long declaring private methods in Categories that are implemented in the class' @implementation I overlooked that Categories generally have their own, separate, implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little clarification about the REASON for the different behavior of unnamed categories (now known as Class Extensions) and normal (named) categories.

The thing is very simple. You can have MANY categories extending the same class, loaded at runtime, without the compiler and linker ever knowing. (consider the many beautiful extensions people wrote to NSObject, that add it functionality post-hoc).

Now Objective-C has no concept of NAME SPACE. Therefore, having iVars defined in a named category could create a symbol clash in runtime. If two different categories would be able to define the same

```
@interface myObject (extensionA) {
 NSString *myPrivateName;
}
@end
@interface myObject (extensionB) {
 NSString *myPrivateName;
}
@end
```

then at the very least, there will be memory overrun at runtime.

In contradiction, Class extensions have NO NAME, and thus there can be only ONE. That's why you can define iVars there. They are assured to be unique.

As for the compiler errors and warnings related to categories and class extensions + ivars and property definitions, I have to agree they are not so helpful, and I spent too much time trying to understand why things compile or not, and how they work (if they work) after they compile.