# Why there is a private in the extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am learning objective-C and I know we can use extension to add some private members to an interface.

But the book said there should be nothing in the ()

I read the following code snippet

```
@interface Tree(Private)
- (void)blah:(int)num;
@end
```

I am wondering why there is Private inside ()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685679/minutia-on-objective-c-categories-and-extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put any name in the class category declaration, usually indicating the purpose of that category.

So in your case author of the code wanted to tell that those methods are for internal use of the class itself and are not intented to be called from other classes

Answer (score 1):

The declaration in your example is precisely called a *category* (not an *extension*).

You can add as many *categories* as you like to any given Class (even if you don't have access to the source code). Categories allow you to add new methods to a class, but not new ivars nor properties. [1]

Each category has a name, which is the bit between parenthesis. There should not be two different *categories* for the same Class with the same name.

When the name is empty, this is called an *extension*. Extensions have some slight differences with *categories*: you can add ivars and properties to extensions and you can only use them for Classes for which you have access to the source code. [1]

Usually, *extensions* (like the example in your book) are declared at the top of the `.m` file, and are used for declaring methods, ivars and/or properties that are to be used only within that file (usually comprised of a single Class).

P.D.: If you really want to add new properties through *categories* as opposed to through *extensions* you can actually do so using associated objects [2][3].

1. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html
2. [Defining a property in iOS class extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252725/defining-a-property-in-ios-class-extension)
3. http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/

Answer (score 0):

In the case that is considered as a category, but since it's on the .m file, it will have the same effect. You can also see the tips from Xcode:

[image]

Being the mid one considered something like `Tree(description)` and the last one `Tree ()`

Answer (score 0):

There are two closely related concepts here: class categories and class extensions. Class categories include a name inside the parenthesis and are most commonly used to add methods to existing classes or to organize methods into logical groups. Class extensions extend the internal implementation of the class (i.e. are used to define private properties, methods, etc).

More details can be found on Apple's dev site:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html